# Camera Calibration Without using cv2.calibrateCamera

Tags: python, opencv, camera-calibration

I am doing camera calibration using cv2.calibrateCamera as follows.

```
ret, matrix, distortion, r_vecs, t_vecs = cv2.calibrateCamera(threedpoints, twodpoints, grayColor.shape[::-1], None, None)
```

But I am required to do it without using this function.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem/question?

Comment: @DanMašek I should not use cv2.calibrateCamera in my code? Do you have any idea how to do that? Please read the question carefully.

Comment: Please do your own research, especially if a class problem. Do not expect to use StackOverflow. It is here to help debug, not provide solutions or write code for you or teach you the basics without OpenCV, etc

Comment: If the same calibration algorithm required, see OpenCV's manual to know the model equations, and implement the solver of the equations.
(What to do will be the same even if you are looking for some other calibration algorithms.)